# The sum of values ​whose second column is 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2021

I have two columns in Excel!
The first column of prices
And the second column of the status, whose values ​​are 1 and 0!
I want to the sum of the prices whose status is 1!
How do I do this?

Columns A1:A5 are for prices |||| Columns B1:B5 are for statuses ||| Section G2 is for the sum total

Comment: What have you tried? I'd think `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` should do what you want. If you can't figure it out, I suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question to improve it (or ask a new if this one has been closed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SumIf formula would be your best fit. It can compare a wide range of data and output specific results.

A1:A5 is the Price.

> 1 is the criteria
> B1:B5 is the status

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5,">1",B1:B5)
```

You can read more about the SumIf function [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)